# hg-git push results in duplicate commit history

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, bitbucket, hg-git

We recently took a repository we had in Mercurial and decided to migrate it to Bitbucket with Git. The initial conversion of HG default to Git master was successful. However, now I'm trying to migrate an old bug fix branch from the HG repo to the Git repo and having problems. I have HG-Git installed and running.

I ran this command to push only this branch to my git repo:

```
hg push ..\git_repo --branch develop/FIX-5021
```

This worked, but not optimally. Specifically, it created a new branch; which had the entire history of the project in it prior to the commits I wanted. I ended up with duplicate commit entries for each commit previous to the fix commits, one in the master branch, one in my FIX-5021 branch.

Is there any way I can migrate this HG branch to my converted Git repo without the duplicate commit entries?